# How to install sshpass on Mac?

Tags: macos, ssh, sshpass

I would like to automate ssh login from my Mac.

It does have a simple solution:

```
sshpass -p my_password ssh m_username@hostname
```

But my problem is installing sshpass on my Mac.

Comment: Why bother with sshpass when you can use ssh keypairs? More secure and dosn't expose password in the process table.

Comment: On OSX run the command `ssh-keygen -b 2048`. It will generate a keypair and store them in `~/.ssh.` as `id_rsa` (private key) and `id_rsa.pub` (public key). Copy `id_rsa.pub` to linux in the directory `~/.ssh/` and name the file `authorized_keys`. From here on when you connect to linux you will not need a password. The private/public keypair will be used.

Comment: Just for someone else who might be trying to follow @alvits very helpful advice: 1) generate the `id_rsa` file on your **local** machine and 2) `scp` the `id_rsa.pub` to the **server's** corresponding folder as suggested and 3) rename the `id_ras.pub` file on the **server**.

Comment: The above answers do NOT answer OP's question.  Good alternative, but not explaining how to install sshpass on Mac.  There are cases where you cannot copy to the remote system (mine is embedded read only filesystem).  So, something like sshpass is a better means to get into the remote.

Comment: While it's good to comment to inform risks, it is unhelpful to withhold direct answers on assumption the user can simply install SSH keys. Try dealing with embedded OS whose root-directory is read-only. Your choices then are continually typing passwords, playing hunt-the-homebrew-tap game, or writing Expect.

Comment: By making users go install this from "random GH repos" the Homebrew developers are actively pushing users toward greater risk since those third-party repos have no eyes on them.  I too am targeting a read-only embedded Linux.

Comment: This answer is still relevant in 2021
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63886356/885886

Comment: It seems with "normal" openssh you can pass in a password these days: https://superuser.com/a/1703039/39364 so you may not need sshpass :)

Comment: Instead of using scp, you can copy RSA public key to the server like so: `ssh-copy-id remoteuser@remotehostname`

Comment: I agree with @ScottPrive and in fact [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74602643/6854564) uses [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) instead of relying on random Github repositories or random non-popular websites that claim to be dedicated to open source software.

Comment: @Kubuntuer82 - TY.  I don't know what's worse here, the lack of understanding what "read only embedded filesystem" means. Or homebrew's devs who do understand it, but actively don't care about the use case.

Comment: Is it safe to use SSHPASS ? it doesn't guarantee that it does not share server user host and password ?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

There are instructions on how to install sshpass here:

https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979

For Mac you will need to install xcode and command line tools then use the unofficial Homewbrew command:

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb > sshpass.rb && brew install sshpass.rb && rm sshpass.rb
```

Comment: In 2020 I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62623099/667301) as the best answer

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work for me ```Error: Calling Non-checksummed download of sshpass formula file from an arbitrary URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract' or 'brew create' and 'brew tap-new' to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.```

Comment: **Update for 2021**: `curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb > sshpass.rb && brew install sshpass.rb && rm sshpass.rb`

Comment: Brew has taps now, see some of the other answers...

Comment: I did not need Xcode, the Command-Line Tools were enough.

Answer (score 252):

**Update 2022:** Unfortunately, Aleks Hudochenkov is no longer updating his repo. There are [a bunch of other repos on GitHub](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=homebrew+sshpass&s=updated&type=Repositories) that purport to contain a Homebrew recipe for sshpass. It's up to you which of them (if any) to trust.

Some years have passed and there is now a proper Homebrew [Tap](https://docs.brew.sh/Taps) for `sshpass`, maintained by [Aleks Hudochenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7458284). To install `sshpass` from this tap, run:

```
brew install hudochenkov/sshpass/sshpass
```

Tap [source](https://github.com/hudochenkov/homebrew-sshpass/blob/master/sshpass.rb)

Comment: Is the source code somewhere? Using something like sshpass without knowing the code is critical

Comment: @muuvmuuv, yes. If you look at [the formula](https://github.com/hudochenkov/homebrew-sshpass/blob/master/sshpass.rb) in [that tap](https://github.com/hudochenkov/homebrew-sshpass), you will see that it downloads the source from https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sshpass/sshpass/1.06/sshpass-1.06.tar.gz and builds it locally.

Comment: Error: Your CLT does not support macOS 11. I use 11.2.

Comment: Same error as @ikreb, `Your CLT does not support macOS 11.` On latest version of Big Sur.

Comment: @kjdion84 This helps me: ``sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`` and
``sudo xcode-select --install``.

Comment: Works on Catalina with XCode 12.3 on 2021-02-18.

Comment: `This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only.` so I can't request bump its version to latest sshpass :(

Comment: @rogerdpack Ah, that's unfortunate. There are a [bunch of repos on GitHub](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=homebrew+sshpass&s=updated&type=Repositories) that purport to contain a Homebrew recipe for sshpass. It's up to you which of them (if any) to trust.

Comment: For what little it's worth, I've forked Aleks' repo above and updated to the latest version of sshpass on sourceforge (1.08).

`brew install stevenhaddox/sshpass/sshpass`

Comment: looks like `sshpass` has to support `ssh` versions to get it working.

Answer (score 47):

Another option in 2020 is this homebrew tap, maintained by [esolitos](https://github.com/esolitos/homebrew-ipa/blob/master/Formula/sshpass.rb#L4)

```
brew install esolitos/ipa/sshpass
```

Comment: This is the only answer which literally answers the question. There are concerns with that - a tiny repo could go rogue (and not be noticed right away). But it is an answer. User is advised to exhaust every possible use case first, as there could be other simpler answers (like maybe if you're dealing with a Dropbear host that doesn't store `authorized_keys` under home directories and that's why your staged public key was rejected, etc)

Comment: this is work for me on 2022. macbook pro m1

Answer (score 31):

Following worked for me

```
curl -O -L  https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/files/sshpass/1.06/sshpass-1.06.tar.gz && tar xvzf sshpass-1.06.tar.gz
cd sshpass-1.06/
./configure
sudo make install
```

Comment: Just make sure you already have xcode installed.  Please google how to do that, here is one of the link (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/install-xcode-command-line-tools/)

Comment: Add `--insecure` to `curl` if you get: **SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired**

Answer (score 19):

Solution provided by ***lukesUbuntu*** from github works for me:

Just use brew

```
$ brew install http://git.io/sshpass.rb
```

Comment: note: this is out of date and points to an old version of sshpass

Comment: @DevisLucato Yes, for the one LF the latest version of sshpass, xcode with sshpass src will lead the way. https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/ Good luck.

Comment: This is now out of date - the comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62623099/1817774 is more current. Thanks @smammy

Comment: `Error: Non-checksummed download of sshpass formula file from an arbitrary URL is unsupported! `brew extract` or `brew create` and `brew tap-new` to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.`

Answer (score 12):

I found that most of the answers listed here are out of date. To install the latest, I ran this and downloaded directly from sourceforge.net, based on other answers here.

```
curl -L https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/files/latest/download -o sshpass.tar.gz && tar xvzf sshpass.tar.gz
cd sshpass-*
./configure
sudo make install
```

Comment: `configure: error: in /Users/ME/sshpass-1.08:
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See config.log for more details`

Comment: This is better than other answers that use a specific and likely outdated version

Answer (score 9):

Please follow the steps below to install `sshpass` in mac.

```
curl -O -L https://fossies.org/linux/privat/sshpass-1.06.tar.gz && tar xvzf sshpass-1.06.tar.gz

cd sshpass-1.06

./configure

sudo make install
```

Comment: Needs to be updated to ```/linux/privat/sshpass-1.09.tar.gz```

Answer (score 5):

I just followed the instructions from [this article](https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/installing-sshpass-osx-mavericks#:%7E:text=You%20can%20do%20this%20by,project%2C%20currently%20available%20on%20sourceforge.) and it helped,

```
curl -O -L http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sshpass/sshpass/1.05/sshpass-1.05.tar.gz && tar xvzf sshpass-1.05.tar.gz

//This creates a directory sshpass-1.05

cd sshpass-1.05
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks, the linked article provides more context

Answer (score 5):

#### Short answer

To avoid having to rely on unknown Github repositories (directly or via Homebrew taps) just use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) :)

Just install MacPorts and then type

```
sudo port install sshpass
```

#### Details / Long answer

The idea is to install sshpass via MacPorts instead of Homebrew.

You can have both Homebrew and MacPorts on the same machine, but be careful as some packages are available on both sources, and in that case you should be consistent in order to avoid conflicts.

In such cases, normally I give priority to Homebrew, but sshpass won't be provided by them, as they explicitly say.

In fact, if you type:

```
brew install sshpass
```

Then the output will also include this sentence:

```
We won't add sshpass because it makes it too easy for novice SSH users to ruin SSH's security.
```

Then in this case MacPorts is the only choice (if you really want to use sshpass).

#### Some links

[Link to the MacPorts project](https://www.macports.org/)
[How to install MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php)
[Link to the sshpass Port on MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/sshpass/)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't even aware macports was still around. :-) This entire page is a shining example to how security can be made WORSE through blind, inflexible opinion and perspective. All these embedded Linux users had to seek lesser-known, fewer-eyeballs repos due to Homebrew's activist stance.

Comment: Yes @ScottPrive you are totally right: perhaps they could put plenty of warnings, or make the package more difficult to install (similarly to what Chrome does when you visit websites with invalid SSL certificates, forcing you to type 'thisisunsafe' on the screen), but they should not completely forbid this, because the consequences will be exactly the ones you said.

Answer (score 3):

For the simple reason:

```
Andy-B-MacBook:~ l.admin$ brew install sshpass
Error: No available formula with the name "sshpass"
We won't add sshpass because it makes it too easy for novice SSH users to
ruin SSH's security.
```

Thus, the answer to do the curl / configure / install worked great for me on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Just a slight update from the previous answer

```
curl -O -L  https://fossies.org/linux/privat/sshpass-1.09.tar.gz && tar xvzf sshpass-1.09.tar.gz
cd sshpass-1.09/
./configure
sudo make install
```

This Worked as on OCT 2021

Answer (score 1):

Aargh, the problem with the outdated links.
Simply go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/
Download latest version and then `tar xvzf` it and finally `cd to the dir where it got unpacked`and install with:
`./configure make sudo make install`
I suppose this will also work on every OS with supported C sdk installed...