# Ansible: To use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program"

Tags: ansible

Recently I created new roles called spd in my existing project. While other script works fine in the setup. This newly created fails. Please point me to what is going wrong here

```
ansible/roles
      spd
        tasks
        templates
        defaults
```

**deploy-spd.yml**

```
 - hosts:
   roles:
     - spd
```

**inventory file**

```
[kube-master]
kubernetes-master-1 ansible_host=10.20.0.225 ansible_user=centos ansible_become=true
kubernetes-master-2 ansible_host=10.20.0.226 ansible_user=centos ansible_become=true
kubernetes-master-3 ansible_host=10.20.0.227 ansible_user=centos ansible_become=true
```

**Failure**

```
bash-4.3# ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory deploy-test-ms.yml --ask-vault-pass
Vault password:

PLAY [kube-master] *************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
Thursday 16 March 2017  13:32:05 +0000 (0:00:00.026)       0:00:00.026 ********
fatal: [kubernetes-master-1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program"}
fatal: [kubernetes-master-2]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program"}
fatal: [kubernetes-master-3]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
kubernetes-master-1 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
kubernetes-master-2 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
kubernetes-master-3 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

**UPDATE:**

```
**With failed script**    

        Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/system/setup.py
<10.20.0.227> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/system/setup.py
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/system/setup.py
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/system/setup.py
<172.23.169.137> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
<10.20.0.225> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
<10.20.0.226> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
   
**With successfull script**    

Thursday 16 March 2017  14:03:49 +0000 (0:00:00.066)       0:00:00.066 ********
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/system/setup.py
<10.20.0.237> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
<10.20.0.237> SSH: EXEC ssh -F ./ssh.cfg -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
-o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=centos -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/ansible-%r@%h:%p' 10.20.0.237 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489673029.48-15997231643297
4 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1489673029.48-159972316432974="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489673029.48-159972316432974 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.20.0.237> PUT /tmp/tmpnHJPbc TO /home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489673029.48-159972316432974/setup.py
<10.20.0.237> SSH: EXEC scp -F ./ssh.cfg -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
-o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=centos -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/ansible-%r@%h:%p' /tmp/tmpnHJPbc '[10.20.0.237]:/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489673029.48-159972316432974/setup.py'
<10.20.0.237> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
<10.20.0.237> SSH: EXEC ssh -F ./ssh.cfg -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
-o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=centos -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/ansible-%r@%h:%p' 10.20.0.237 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489673029.48-159972316432974/ /home/cento
s/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489673029.48-159972316432974/setup.py && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Comment: It has little to do with your Ansible playbooks. Does SSH work properly? Can you access the targets with key authentication for user `centos`?

Comment: @techraf I am able to do ssh on centos vm.and ansible -i inventory/inventory -m ping all works fine.

Comment: @Chris_vr you have different IPs for successful run (.237) and for failed run (.225-.227). Please double check this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue was because of use of attribute **ansible_password** in `/defaults/main.yml`. I have maintained lots of variables in this file to be used by script along with attribute ansible_password.

```
- include_vars: "{{ role_path}}/defaults/main.yml"
```

The attribute `ansible_password` is reserved for use by Ansible. Now I changed the variable name to `ansible_pass` and it is working fine.

Comment: To restate this: having "ansible_password" defined will supersede your private key setting, and cause ansible to want to use `sshpass` -- usually this is due to group_vars combining in an unexpected way.

Answer (score 109):

It is the host machine which needs the `sshpass` program installed. Again, this error message of:

> ERROR! to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program

Applies to the HOST (provisioner) not the GUEST (machine(s) being provisioned). Thus install `sshpass` on the provisioner.

**Install sshpass on Ubuntu 16.04 or similar**

```
apt-get install sshpass
```

**Install sshpass on Mac OS**

```
brew install hudochenkov/sshpass/sshpass
```

Source: [How to install sshpass on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255660/how-to-install-sshpass-on-mac)

Comment: For CentOS / Red Hat: `sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/sshpass-1.06-2.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: is it bad to install sshpass on a production server ?  https://www.tecmint.com/sshpass-non-interactive-ssh-login-shell-script-ssh-password/

Answer (score 33):

Just to add to various answers above and this method directly resolves and answers the main issue as stated in the title.

It is possible to pass the parameter using `paramiko`, which is another pure `python` implementation of `SSH`. This is supported by ansible and would be the **preferred** option as it relies on less cross language dependancies that has to be separately managed; Thus this essentially by-passes the need for another library installed on your host machine : `sshpass`.

instead of using the connection ssh as below :

> $ansible-playbook -i hosts -v -b -c ssh --ask-pass myplaybook.yml

you can and will find it easier to use the following :

> $ansible-playbook -i hosts -v -b -c paramiko --ask-pass myplaybook.yml

if you are interested, you can read more here: http://www.paramiko.org/

thanks for additional comments as mention, via the `paramiko` way, you can also set it in your inventory file, or set it as a playbook option.

Comment: ...which you can specify in your `inventory` file with `ansible_connection=paramiko`, instead of the CLI param.

Comment: Yet another way is to set it as a playbook option, `connection: paramiko_ssh`. I commonly use this on a single "bootstrap" playbook that sets up new hosts with authorized public SSH keys. Then everything else keeps the default. Enabling Paramiko in inventory (or `ansible.cfg`) is more permanently using a slower method.

Comment: ansible 2.7.10. The param in ansible.cfg should be:    
[defaults]  
transport = paramiko

Answer (score 8):

For macOS

```
brew install esolitos/ipa/sshpass
```

To quickly verify I would just ping

```
ansible all -i path/to/host -m ping
```

Answer (score 7):

For UBUNTU

`sudo apt install sshpass`

After this run ansible script

Answer (score 1):

Use ansible_password to ansible_pass and that will do it!

Answer (score 1):

for MacOS `brew install sshpass` resolved this issue for me

Comment: It appears sshpass was renamed to sshs. Given error: `We won't add sshpass because it makes it too easy for novice SSH users to`

Answer (score 0):

> brew install hudochenkov/sshpass/sshpass

this path seem ok

Answer (score 0):

in your client machine install sshpass.
Ubuntu: `sudo apt install sshpass`
CentOs: `yum install sshpass`

Answer (score 0):

For centOS,
use `sudo yum install sshpass`