# Using Ansible authorized_key module to copy SSH key fails with sshpass needed erro

Tags: ssh, ansible, copy, key

I am trying to copy my .pub key file located in ~/.ssh/mykey.pub to one of the remote hosts using Ansible.

I have a very simple playbook containing this task:

```
- name: SSH-copy-key to target
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Copying local SSH key to target
      ansible.posix.authorized_key:
        user: '{{ ansible_user_id }}'
        state: present
        key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/mykey.pub') }}"
```

Due to the fact that the host is 'new', I am adding a --ask-pass parameter to be asked for the SSH password on the first connection attempt.
However, I receive the error that I need to install the sshpass program.

The following is being returned:

```
➜  ansible ansible-playbook -i inventory.yaml ssh.yaml --ask-pass
SSH password: 

PLAY [SSH-copy-key to target] ********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************
fatal: [debian]: FAILED! => {"msg": "to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords or pkcs11_provider, you must install the sshpass program"}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************
debian                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

➜  ansible
```

I am executing Ansible from a MacBook. I tried replacing the 'key' key with the URL to my github account. The same error appears.

```
key: https://github.com/myuseraccount.keys
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if you read the errormessage, it says you should install the sshpass program. So you could take the explanation from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255660/how-to-install-sshpass-on-mac

Comment: This seems odd to me. Especially, when I tried to brew and search for sshpass: "If you meant "sshpass" specifically:
We won't add sshpass because it makes it too easy for novice SSH users to
ruin SSH's security."

Comment: Then don't use a password with ssh in Ansible. Else install sshpass as very clearly asked.

Comment: I find it odd because brew tells me that sshpass is suspicous. Then, I ask myself whether I am doing something wrong in my Ansible yaml instruction set. It seems to be a corner case which in addition, I cannot believe that this is a rare occasion.